# a problem with BitmapEx.h

Tags: c++

i write this code but it gives an error. why it does not include the header file?

coding:

```
#include "BitmapEx.h"
CBitmapEx bitmapEx;
bitmapEx.Load(_T("Enter bitmap source file path here..."));
bitmapEx.Rotate(45);
bitmapEx.Sepia();
bitmapEx.Scale(50, 50);
bitmapEx.Draw(hDC);
bitmapEx.Save(_T("Enter bitmap destination file path here..."));
```

error:
Cannot open include file: 'BitmapEx.h': No such file or directory

Comment: Welcome to SO! Next time, please use the 101010 button to format your code.

Comment: thank! :) i will use that button

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, like the error message tells you, it cannot find the file. Did you spell the name correctly? Is it in the current directory, or if not, in the current include path?

Comment: the spelling is correct. may be it is not in the directory,how can i load it in the current directory?

Comment: @Sweety Khan:  How to load it into the proper directory is a function of your OS and build system.  Your question cannot be properly answered as asked, since it's missing too much information.